# How to I read from Kafka Queue?

Tags: publish-subscribe, apache-kafka

The following is a great example of how to use Kafka as a publish subscribe framework:

https://github.com/abhioncbr/Kafka-Message-Server/blob/master/README.md

I am desperately looking for a similar example that shows how to use kafka as queuing framework. That means as soon as one client retrieves the message, no other client should have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the group names used by the consumer. The documentations says:

> If all the consumer instances have the same consumer group, then this works just like a traditional queue balancing load over the consumers.
>
> If all the consumer instances have different consumer groups, then this works like publish-subscribe and all messages are broadcast to all consumers.

This answers my question.